# Linear Algebra - vector space of linear transformations

Tags: linear-algebra

Let the $\Bbb R$-vectorspace V be all the transformations from the finite set $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ to $\Bbb R$

$$V:= T(\{1,2,3,4,5,\},\Bbb R)$$

Let the function $f:V\rightarrow \Bbb R$ be defined by $f(\phi)=\sum_{i=0}^5 \phi(i)$ for $\phi \in V$

I am not sure i understand this notation correctly,  $f(\phi)=\sum_{i=0}^5 \phi(i)$ for $\phi \in V$ means for example if $\phi(1), f=1*1+2+1+...+5*1$, is this correct?

And in this case, the basis of the space V would simply be the set $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ Thou I was wondering the dimension of V would be 5*5=25?

Comment: I understand that a **transformation** $\phi$ is understood as a function from the finite set $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ to the real numbers. 

For your example I understand $\phi=1$ means the function which is constantly one, and in that case we'd have: $f(\phi)=\phi(1)+\dots+\phi(5) = 1+\dots +1 = 5$.

As for the last question, note that every function from a finite set to $\mathbb{R}$ can be written as a (unique!) linear combination of the functions $\delta_1,\dots,\delta_5$, where $\delta_i(j) = 1$ if $i=j$ and $0$ if $i\neq j$. That gives $\dim V = 5$.

Comment: You have either typos or undefined symbols here: when you write $\phi\in U$ do you mean $\phi\in V$? Or what's $U$? Please edit. And then in your example what do you mean by $\phi=1$? - isn't $\phi$ meant to be in $V$?

Comment: @topolosaurus Sorry there were some mistakes in my question, i corrected them now. But i think now i got it.

Comment: @ancientmathematician yes there was some mistakes im so sorry,

Comment: It's no good saying "for example $\phi(1)$". That's like saying "for example $3\pi+23$". Why not do a more sensible example: Let $\phi$ be the function $\phi(1)=15$, $\phi(2)=23$,$\phi(3)=-\pi$,$\phi(4)=1$,$\phi(5)=-1015$. Now what is $f(\phi)$?

Comment: @ancientmathematician $f(\phi)=15+23-\pi+1+-1015$....now i got it....i thought $\phi$ is the same as $f$....

Comment: @ancientmathematician i have one little follow up question, the space $v*$ would be the dual space with $V,\Bbb R$, the dual space would have the dimension 25, is that correct? Since i was lookking for the dimension of V, it's just 5 because we only have 5 elements. However, if im looking for a basis of V, then its just $1$ because every element in V can be a scalar multiple of 1. Is this correct=? but it has dimension 5....so {1,1,1,1,1}?

Comment: @Berci has now answered it : $V$ a $5$ dimensional space of *functions*, the question isn't about dual spaces.

Answer (score 1):

$V$ is the set of all *functions* $\phi:\{1,2,3,4,5\}\to\Bbb R$.

The point is that such a function is uniquely determined by the 5-tuple $(\phi(1),\dots,\phi(5))$ of its values, and these values can be arbitrary real numbers.
The space will have dimension $5$.

So, for a given $\phi$, $f(\phi)=\sum_{i=1}^5\phi(i)$ is the sum of the 5 values $\phi(1),\dots,\phi(5)$ it takes (i.e., of the coordinates of the corresponding tuple).